# What is max integer value for mysqli prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli

After asking and reading many q/a here I newly started a new project using prepared statments

my question is about types

```
mysqli_stmt->bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

for $types 
i : is integer okay what is it's max value ... can it handle bigint ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maximum value of int that is handled by 32 bit MySQL is 2147483647
and yes, you can handle bigger ints
just check it's value before binding param and if it's greater than 2147483647 use type 's' instead of 'i'. MySQL will handle it itself, I use this method for seven years already